# Sending EMails with Indy with multiple CCs. If one is incorrect nobody recieves the mail

Tags: email, delphi, indy, indy10

I currently setting up a little tool for my company that is used to send info-mails to specific user groups.
But if one or more email addresses are incorrect (missing letter etc.) I get following error and the email isn't sent at all:

EIdSMTPReplyError

Requested action not taken: mailbox unavailable
invalid DNS MX or A/AAAA resource record

I set up the email like this:

- adding the first email as main recipient
- adding all others to the cclist

Is there a way to set up the email so atleast the other recipients are getting the email?

Some Infos:

- Delphi 7
- Indy 10

Thanks in advance <3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`TIdSMTP` has an `OnFailedRecipient` event:

```
type
  TIdSMTPFailedRecipient = procedure(Sender: TObject; const AAddress, ACode, AText: String;
    var VContinue: Boolean) of object;
```

`AAddress` is the email address, and `ACode` and `AText` contain the error details.

If `VContinue` is set to True (the default when `OnFailedRecipient` is assigned), the failed email is skipped and the next recipient is attempted.

The `EIdSMTPReplyError` exception is raised if either:

- `OnFailedRecipient` is not assigned when a recipient fails.
- `VContinue` is set to False.
- all recipients fail, regardless of `OnFailedRecipient`.